# How to use boost's deadline_timer::asynch_wait in a loop?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, mfc, boost-asio

I'm having a MFC application (VC10) where I'm using  deadline_timer::asynch_wait() running in a while-loop in a separated thread. Due to fact, the waiting period can be some minutes or even more, I'm using asych_wait to able to interrupt the wait. My problem is that the timer callback is called only once, while the first execution. When the loop executes for the second time, the callback isn't called any more. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
header:
std::unique_ptr<boost::asio::deadline_timer> m_timer;

cpp:
UINT camThread1( LPVOID pParam )
{
  CDlg* pView = (CMyDlg*) pParam;
  boost::asio::io_service io_service;

  // to be able to interrupt the timer from the GUI Thread
  pView->m_timer.reset(new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service)); 

  boost::posix_time::ptime lastLoop;
  typedef boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> time_traits_t;
  lastLoop = time_traits_t::now();

  while (1)
  {
    boost::posix_time::ptime nextFrameTime;
    // calculate the time to wait
    nextFrameTime = lastFrameTime + boost::posix_time::seconds(pView->m_interval);

    // start the timer
    pView->m_timer->expires_at(nextFrameTime);
    pView->m_timer->async_wait(boost::bind(&CDlg::timer_handler, pView, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    io_service.run();

    DWORD dwWaitResult = WaitForSingleObject(pView->m_timerEvent, INFINITE);
    switch (dwWaitResult) 
    {
      // check results
    }
    lastLoop = time_traits_t::now(); // get the current time

    // do something
  }
}
```

My timer callback looks as follows:

```
void CDlg::timer_handler(const boost::system::error_code& error)
{
  if (!error || error == boost::asio::error::operation_aborted)
  {
    SetEvent(m_timerEvent);
  } else {
    //throw std::exception(...);
  }
}
```

My Event is created as follows:

```
m_timerEvent = CreateEvent( NULL, FALSE, FALSE, TEXT("timerEvent"));
```

Any suggestion? please...

Tnx in advance & cheers
greg

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved it after checking some tutorials/examples and reading the documentation carefully. 
First of all the io_service.run() call is blocking until all work has finished and there are no more handlers to be dispatched. This makes the signalisation using events unnecessary!

Secondly the io_service.run() needs to be reset prior to any second or later set of invocations!
It works now with following code:

```
UINT camThread1( LPVOID pParam )
{
CDlg* pView = (CMyDlg*) pParam;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

// to be able to interrupt the timer from the GUI Thread
pView->m_timer.reset(new boost::asio::deadline_timer(io_service)); 

boost::posix_time::ptime lastLoop;
typedef boost::asio::time_traits<boost::posix_time::ptime> time_traits_t;
lastLoop = time_traits_t::now();
while (1)
{
  boost::posix_time::ptime nextFrameTime;
  // calculate the time to wait
  nextFrameTime = lastFrameTime + boost::posix_time::seconds(pView->m_interval);

  // start the timer
  pView->m_timer->expires_at(nextFrameTime);
  pView->m_timer->async_wait(boost::bind(&CDlg::timer_handler, pView, boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  if(io_service.stopped()) {
    io_service.reset();
  }
  io_service.run();

  lastLoop = time_traits_t::now(); // get the current time

  // do something
}
```

Comment: so, what is timer_handler?

Comment: That's the handler of the deadline_timer. The handler is going to be called when the timer expire. See my question above, but other to it no event need to be set!